# Scraping a main table with sub tables with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

I am trying to scrape a table that appears to have nested sub-tables. I originally tried to write a loop that would go further into the sub-tables but I am having difficulty parsing it. The website is https://www.brilliantearth.com/design-your-own-engagement-ring/?nav=1 and I am trying to grab the elements of the table to store into a Pandas dataframe using BeautifulSoup in Python. Each of the rows in the table has a tag called "inner item."

It appears that there is a separate table for column headers and another table that lists all the prices. *How do I parse the cell elements to place into my list?*

```
import requests

import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.brilliantearth.com/design-your-own-engagement-ring/?nav=1'

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')

# Find tables
all_tables=soup.find_all('table')
all_tables

# Select table with content we want
right_table = all_tables[-1]
right_table

# Generate lists
COMPARE=[]
SHAPE=[]
CARAT=[]
COLOR=[]
CLARITY=[]
CUT=[]
ORIGIN=[]
PRICE=[]

# Add elements from cells to corresponding list
for row in right_table.findAll("tr"):
    cells = row.findAll('td')

    COMPARE.append(cells[0])
    SHAPE.append(cells[0])
    CARAT.append(cells[0])
    COLOR.append(cells[0])
    CLARITY.append(cells[0])
    CUT.append(cells[0])
    ORIGIN.append(cells[0])
    PRICE.append(cells[0])
```

Comment: Did you have a specific issue you need help in fixing or are you asking someone to provide you with working scraper code?

Comment: Apologies, the question in italics. I can't subset just the table that I want. There appear to be 5 tables on the page but I can only see one when I look at the website.

Comment: If they're not in the page source when using the developer tools in your browser than they're either included in some javascript or coming from ajax/similar requests... in which case you need to trace where the data is coming from that your browser is displaying and reproduce the appropriate actions to get the same...

Comment: Thanks Jon. Yes. They are in the page source but each row is listed as a table. This is where my confusion lies. I am calling "right_table", but then there are row tables in "right_table" that represent each diamond''s 8 qualities that I am trying to put in a list.